# How to Clear instance filed afterClass in Junit?

Tags: java, junit, theory

I am looking a way to collect and publish these `myResults`. But Junit `@AfterClass` only supports static method.

If I am having a super class If multiple test cases are running it can be ugly. Any idea how I can resolve this? If I use after, I won't get the full output collected by myresult

```
abstract class MainTestCase{
  static List<String> myResults = new ArrayList();

  @AfterClass public static void WrapUp() {

    //code to write the myResults to text file  goes here
    System.out.println("Wrapping Up");
    myResults.clear()
  }

}

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryAfterClassTest extends MainTestCase {

  @DataPoint
  public static String a = "a";

  @DataPoint
  public static String b = "bb";

  @DataPoint
  public static String c = "ccc";

  @Theory
  public void stringTest(String x, String y) {
    myResults.add(x + " " + y);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
  }      
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make `WrapUp()` static?

Comment: Also, you might want to look at using parameterized tests. These might be able to allow you to get rid of the inheritance hierarchy all together.

Comment: @Code-Guru How do I make sure other test cases that are extending from the super class is not affected.. I clearly don't wanna mix them up. any advice on that?

Comment: @Code-Guru my real code comprises of objects rather, so Theory suits me well.

Comment: You mean it can be ugly if multiple test cases are running in parallel?

Comment: "How do I make sure other test cases that are extending from the super class is not affected." @Macon I don't know what you mean. Can you modify your example to show two subclasses of `MainTestCase`and illustrate what you want to happen?

Comment: @NandorKracser exactly.. If I have multiple test cases parallel. it can get ugly. How can i go about it?

Comment: Is using an ``@After`` annotated method a way to go? It is not static and executed after each testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `List<String> myResults;` into a `ThreadLocal` may solve the problem, this how all your parallel test cases would have their own instance of `myResults`.

```
static ThreadLocal<List<String>> myResults = new ThreadLocal<>();

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    myResults.set(new ArrayList<String>());
}

// use it later in your code
@Test
public void myTestCase() {
     myResults.get().add("result");
}
```